# How to read external electronic device in android

Tags: android, eid

I'm looking to develop an android app that communicates with an external Electronic ID device such as an ear tag on a farm animal.  I've been looking around for details on how i can do this, but i've come up with not much.  A few government leaflets, or high level docs.  I was hoping someone here has some experience with this, and con point me in the right direction?

I'm looking for a spec on the EID, how i can communicate with the device and the data i communicate with.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Update:  The reader is Allflex RS420 reader.  Android api: 17

Comment: Your question sounds a bit too broad. What kind of devices are we talking here? What technology do they use (ex: Bluetooth LE)?

Comment: I've just updated the question with a little more detail.  The device is the Allflex RS420 (http://www.allflex.co.uk/rs420-eid-reader-c-114-p-138), and android version is around 17.   HTH